# VS 2008 resource type error while changing language

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

While changing the language of the resource elements in my visual studio project from english to azerbaijan I am getting this error:

> error RC2144 : PRIMARY LANGUAGE ID not a number

and that line is :

```
LANGUAGE LANG_AZERI_CYRILLIC, SUBLANG_AZERI_CYRILLIC
```

What's happening here?

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>
#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#include "targetver.h"
#endif
#include "winres.h"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the line `LANGUAGE LANG_AZERI_CYRILLIC, SUBLANG_AZERI_CYRILLIC` from the resource file to `LANGUAGE LANG_AZERI, SUBLANG_AZERI_CYRILLIC` as defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
It seems like visual studio generated that code erroneously.

Answer (score 7):

The error is because the resource designer using constant (language ID) defined in **winres.h**, but the **winres.h** is not included in the resource file.

Add this line to resource.rc (view code as text, not from dialog editor), this will fix the problem:

```
#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#include <winres.h>
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
```

P.S: you need also to define **APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS** to keep include winres.h because Visual Studio will always keep removing *#include*

Comment: With Visual Studio 2015 I had to add these lines to `resource.h` as they kept being removed from the `.rc` file.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `#include <windows.h>` to your resources.rc file.  Sometimes the line is not generated.

It's lame, I know.

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: Fixed - link was not relevant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio 2015 These lines always been overwritten when editing resources.
To add this includes with Visual Studio 2015:

1. Go to "Resource View" Ctrl+Shift+E
2. Right click on the resource.rc file and select resourceincludes
3. Add to the write protected symbols:

   #include "winres.h"